# Firebase cloud function "Your client does not have permission to get URL /200 from this server"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just made a firebase cloud function :

```
exports.deleteAfterSevenDays = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {...
```

I deployed the function and got a function URL. When I request this url from my browser I get the following message :

> "Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /200
>   from this server."

I have just updated to firebase Blaze plan because I thought there were limitations with Spark plan, but it still doesn't work.

In my firebase cloud function logs it is written "Function execution took 572 ms, finished with status code: 302".

My cron job "has been disabled automatically because of too many failed executions".

Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: Hi @Alex9494 did you manage to solve this one? Cheers.

Comment: Hi Ivan not yet but I do intend to solve it "soon"... The first who gets the answer gives it to the other one ! ;)

Comment: Seems I found the cause of my problem. It was simply a crash in the function I was invoking. Once I fixed it, request started to return 200.

Comment: It was an issue in my firebase cloud function code as well. Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end() https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 178):

Cloud function should have a role with member called "All users" to invoke this function from anywhere/anyone irrespective of an authorization.

**Without Authorization:**

1. Go to the cloud function tab
2. Select your cloud function (check box)
3. Click "Add members" under Permissions tab in the right side
4. Enter "allUsers" under "New memebers"
5. Select Role as "Cloud Functions -> Cloud Functions Invoker"
6. Save
7. Test your cloud function by just pasting it in the browser

**With Authorization:**

It's always a good practice to set authorization on your cloud functions

Note: Cloud functions throwing error with "403 Forbidden - Your client does not have permission to get URL" should be called by authorized users.

Simple test:

1. Click on Cloud shell(icon) terminal in the top [of the page](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions)
2. type: `gcloud auth print-identity-token`
3. copy the generated token
4. forming Authorization key to be passed while calling cloud function

   4.1 `Authorization: bearer generated_token`
5. Use above Authorization key while calling your cloud function

**Note:**

1. Never make a cloud function available to allUsers

Comment: I tried with the Authorization, but the token seems to be expiring. I could not use the same token from yesterday :(

Comment: This token is the idToken - it is valid only 3600 seconds, after that you should update it.
Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Comment: Note that this is the Google Cloud interface to the Functions, not the Firebase interface -- go to : https://console.cloud.google.com/functions

Comment: If we generate token using the above suggested method, it will be valid only 1 hr.
Then, we can't use same token again.
Is there any way to generate permanent token so that cloud function will work as long as correct token is being provided?

Comment: If you suggest to "Never make a cloud function available to allUsers" what's the best practice for authentication then? Do you recommend to generate  a token for every request made to ones functions? Isn't it sufficient to use Firebase Auth within the function and simply set the access for the API to "allUsers"?

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! BTW, I was facing CORS errors on the browser console. I had the described error (in the question) while trying on Postman. Your answer helped a lot.

Comment: Allowing the function to run without authorization was the solution for me. Because I am doing all my security checks in the function anyway, I needed the function to be executable at least.

Answer (score 55):

From Cloud Function docs:

> Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any
>   Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw
>   HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly make these functions
>   public, or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new
>   functions.

In my case the CLI version was out of date. If you currently get the 403 error, try this:

1. Delete your Cloud Functions
2. Update Firebase CLI `npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. Re-deploy your functions

Comment: That solved my problem. I installed the lastest firebase-tools, deleted my function on the FIrebase console and redeployed it. Et voilá. THANK YOU!

Comment: Besides updating cli, I had to enable unauthenticated function invocation as given here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

Comment: FFFFFFFF It works, I've made it work before just by changing the folder and name of the functions and was really weirded out by that. But deleting the functions and re-uploading works. I could add up too that yu should delete the "lib" folder if you're using firebase functions. Or your build folder. And then re-uploading. Thank you!!!

Comment: Also, the new cloud functions permissions can be set up incorrectly if there is an error during first deployment - deleting the function and re-deploying fixed this for me

Comment: Do not pass this answer up. It still works as of March 2023

Answer (score 51):

**To be clear:**

1. Go to your function (make sure your project is selected):

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/details/us-central1/ssr

2. Click Permissions Tab
3. Click Add Permissions
4. **New Principals:** `allUsers`
   **Role:** `Cloud Functions Invoker`

Done.

J

Answer (score 15):

If you face this in 2020 it might also be due to a different access behaviour:

> Note: As of January 15, 2020, HTTP functions require authentication by
> default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated
> invocation at or after deployment.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

Comment: The more specific link: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment

Answer (score 15):

Here are the steps

- **Go the Google Cloud Console(Not Firebase Console)** -> Search For Cloud Functions to see the list of functions
- Click the checkbox next to the function to which you want to grant
  access.
- Click Permissions at the top of the screen. The Permissions panel
  opens.
- Click Add principal.
- In the New principals field, type allUsers.
- Select the role Cloud Functions > Cloud Functions Invoker from the
- Select a role drop-down menu.
- Click Save.

Answer (score 13):

Changing the IAM role(Cloud Functions Invoker) for targeted cloud function to **allUsers** should solve this issue. https://console.cloud.google.com/functions

Comment: I am having the same issue - can you please clarify what you mean by 'for targeted cloud function to allUsers'?

Comment: This looks to be a security risk? Can you please verify whether changing to allUsers does not have any security risks?

Comment: @Nikhil Not, always that you are dealing with public https functions and maybe custom handling auth inside them.

Answer (score 9):

This might be far fetched but if you have interrupted a cloud function deployment, then redeployed the function (which lead to an error), and after that you redeployed the function successfully this could have caused the issue.

I am trying to reproduce, but simple deleting the function in the firebase console and redeploying worked for me.

Comment: It isn't far-fetched, it happened to me. Steps:
1. deployed a function with a syntax error, got Cloud Errors is having issues error (wrong, sigh)
2. re-deployed with corrected code, thought everything was ok
3. saw stripe webhooks (which hit functions) were failing with `Your client does not have permission to get URL`
4. tried deploying functions again - didn't fix the error
4. found this post, deleted all functions, redeployed again - fixed

Comment: This has happened to me as well. I've pulled my hair out trying to understand exactly what I did wrong, only for everything to work again after a delete and redeploy of my fussy function!

Answer (score 7):

### Enable access from Postman project:

1. Open https://console.cloud.google.com/functions
2. Open cloud shell (right top terminal icon)
3. Write: `gcloud auth print-identity-token`
4. Copy your token and open your Posman
5. Right click on your collection -> Edit
6. Authorization -> Choose type `OAuth 2.0`
7. Paste your token in the Access Token

Note: You can do the same for a single request or folder.

Comment: this token will be valid for 1h only?

Answer (score 6):

it happens to me after i  upgraded all NPM packages and then deployed...
i delete all the functions from the cloude and re-deplyed them. it solve me this error immediately. without change permisions or any other cahnge

Comment: This worked for me - note that I previously tried to deploy it using node 21.6.1 on mac which failed and might have caused the wrong permissions. Deleting and re-deploying using linux and node 20.5.1 solved the permission issue.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the cloud function tab
2. Click [thee dots on the right hand side of your function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Big7.png)
3. Click "Go to cloud run service" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUdbp.png)
4. On Cloud run, click security tab
5. Under Authentication Card, select "Allow unauthenticated invocations" [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvS7D.png)

Comment: tried several options above with no luck. This one that worked for me (thanks @Cody) The wins of giving the zero vote new guy a go!

Answer (score 3):

In **2023**

In my case, I just delete all functions/files that I have created and deploy/upload all files again.

[image]

then deploy again

[image]

then look like this

[image]

[image]

final result
[image]

Comment: thank you so much for this hint. Works now ‍

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone is encountering this and has tried all the permissions stuff above in Google Cloud Console...

In my scenario, it turns out I was trying to replace a very old function (like years old) with a new function of the **same function name**. I tried redeploying the function a few times but nothing worked.

**I needed to delete the function manually from Google Cloud Console** and then redeploy the function. This fixed the issue for me and likely blew out the cobwebs causing it to malfunction.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't make sense, or not a real solution but I solved it by making my account an `Owner` of the Firebase project. It was working nice while I was `Editor` but stopped working suddenly and setting my account as `Owner` solved it for now.

I guess it has to do with certain account having proper access to the `Service Account` which is the actual interface with Firebase Functions and Google Cloud API.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I deployed a new cloud function to the firebase project today and I am not able to execute it. Giving exactly the same error. 

Existing functions present in the firebase project are working fine. So it looks like the issue is for recently newly deployed functions.

Comment: same problem here. can you guys find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made error in Postman
when I typed Body of Request, I didn't switched format from Text to JSON.

Check that part.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

> Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either explicitly make these functions public or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new functions.

You only need to create permissions if you are using old versions of the CLI, because they are by default `private`. Using newer versions >7.7.0, should not happen.

If this happens, run `npm install -g firebase-tools` to get the lastest CLI, go to your Firebase console, delete all the existing functions and deploy again.

For this case there is no need to do anything in google cloud console.