# Same Firebase HTTPS request function works or doesn't depending on the environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

At work every developer has an own Firebase testing environment. I was requested to import some data into Firestore into the environment of a coworker that's on vacation now, for that we use an API that's basically a HTTPS request triggered function.

I'm trying now using Postman and for some reason, the POST requests I'm making into my env work perfectly fine, I get the expected response:

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "message": "Operation successful"
}
```

Wheres as the same request with the same header and body doesn't work on his environment, I get this error, which I've never seen before:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
    <h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/importAPI/import/event</code> from this server.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

The exact same function was deployed recently into both environments, so I'm really clueless about what could be causing this. Does it have to do with some settings my colleage has on his env?

Thanks in advance for your help, if you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944789/14378609

For some reason the function was missing a "Cloud Functions Invoker" role. I went into the GCP Console and added it, the problem was immediately solved:

[image]