# Firebase forbidden GET url response on init

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Have deployed a few firebase functions (according to docs)

```
firebase init
```

Changed the code to something like

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
exports.getUsers = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('users').get().then(data => {
      const users = data.map(user => user.data());
      return res.json(users);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
  });

  exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hello, World!');
  });
```

Deployed it.

```
firebase deploy
```

And as an end result both of the functions return

> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL
> /getUsers from this server.
>
> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL
> /helloWorld from this server.

In the firebase admin console I see that functions exist, and they are there, and I am using same exact urls that the terminal gave me & are on the firebase admin console.

Any ideas?

PS. Located in Estonia.

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, well the proposed answer really didn't help, but what I did find out is that, Google Cloud functions are not free, and I must pay up in order to start using hence the error..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll reopen your question. Note that normally, for your Cloud Functions (which do not include a call to a non-Google service), you should not need to pay, unless you go above the free Spark plan limits (see https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

To solve this issue I had to use my brain and check the dashboard for cloud functions. Cloud functions do not return a 500 error unlike most common APIs, instead inside of the dashboard I found out that:

```
TypeError: data.map is not a function
admin.firestore.collection.get.then.data ( /user_code/index.js:10 )
```

Meaning my 'application' was crashing, oddly enough it was giving me a 403 error.
For good measure I also followed this:

[Firebase cloud function "Your client does not have permission to get URL /200 from this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511677/firebase-cloud-function-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url-200-fr)