# Google cloud function call from postman returning google login auth check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, postman

I'm making a call in Postman to a function I've uploaded to GCP. But the response I get is the HTML of a Google auth web page.

[image: Postman]

I've generated the auth token I need and include it in the headers. I've also removed auth blocks from the function in GCP just in case, and added `Viewer` permissions to `allUsers` in GCP. I'm still forbidden when I try to access from the browser - although according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511677/firebase-cloud-function-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url-200-fr) that should resolve the issue at least in Postman.

Is there some way I can log in on Postman so I'm not prompted for the auth? Or bypass it altogether?

[image: GCP]

Answer (score 1):

For `allUsers` the role should be `Cloud Functions Invoker` rather than `Viewer`.

[image]