# GCP API Gateway route returns Google Sign-In page instead of expected response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-api-gateway

While following the documentation for [setting up GCP's API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-console), I run into an issue that when I make a call to the endpoint, like so:

```
curl --request POST 'https://my-dev-project-XXX.wl.gateway.dev/helloWorld?key=XXX'
```

it returns an HTML page to authenticate with a Google Sign-in rather than the appropriate response of: `"Hello World!"`

##### Problem with function name?

I know the Cloud Function `helloWorld` exists, because if I change the cURL request above to be something like:

```
curl --request POST 'https://my-dev-project-XXX.wl.gateway.dev/helloWorldButChangeTheName?key=XXX'
```

it returns:

```
{"message":"The current request is not defined by this API.","code":404}
```

##### Problem with API Key?

I know the API key is valid because if I change it to `YYY`, I get:

```
{"code":400,"message":"INVALID_ARGUMENT:API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."}
```

##### Problem with Request Method?

I know the Request method of POST is correct because if I change it to GET, it returns:

```
{"message":"The current request is matched to the defined url template \"/helloWorld\" but its http method is not allowed","code":405}
```

##### Problems with authorization?

There are a few similar StackOverflow resolved issues with Cloud Functions generally [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69150933/6090140) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47511677/6090140); however, this isn't the same issue.  I know this because I have made the actual Cloud Function publicly accessible without requiring authorization.  So if I call:

```
curl --request POST 'https://us-west2-my-dev-project.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld'
```

I get back `"Hello World!"`.

##### Problems with Service account roles?

Following the documentation for [configuring a service account for the gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#configuring_a_service_account), I made sure to set the two roles:

- Service Account User
- Cloud Functions Invoker

I'm not certain what it looks like if I don't have these set correctly (as I found the answer before reaching the conclusion that something could be wrong here), but these settings should be sufficient.

### API Config File

The only "significant" difference I have different from the [documented tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-console) is my config file, which is:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: XXX
  description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  # different name than tutorial
  /helloWorld:
    post:
      summary: Greet a user
      # different id than tutorial
      operationId: helloWorld
      x-google-backend:
        # different endpoint than tutorial
        address: https://us-central1-my-prod-project.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
      security:
        - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Sign-in screen caused a lot of confusion here as the issue doesn't seem one that would produce such a result.  You'd think it'd be an issue with authentication, but it's not.  Instead, there are two issues with the API Config File, both regarding the `address`:

1. The region is different than the Cloud Function's.  The Cloud Function is deployed on `us-west2` whereas the API Config file has it set to `us-central1` (what is shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-console#securing_access_by_using_an_api_key)).
2. The project ID is different than the Cloud Function's.  The Cloud Function has the ID of `my-dev-project` whereas the API Config file has it set to `my-prod-project`.  This is because I have two different environments I was trying this out on and messed it up.

I imagine other subtle issues with the API Config file may cause the response to be the Google Sign-in page as well so if my two points above didn't solve your issue, look for other differences, such as the path names and `operationId`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same case, but upon looking at your api config file, I can say that I had the same issue with the api gateway and the resolution was changing the x-google-backend address to what cloud function url is instead of what it is said in the documents (the [document](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-console#creating_an_api_definition) says it's

> https://region-projectID.cloudfunctions.net/CloudFunctionName

but that doesn't work. You can find the url by looking at the trigger tab of your cloud function in GCP, it would be something like:

```
  x-google-backend:
    # different endpoint than tutorial
    address:https://<the cloud function url>/helloWorld
```