# Get current date and time from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to add this code in Firebase Cloud Function:

```
exports.getTime = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
    return Date.now()
})
```

But I am getting this error upon checking on a browser but I am planning to use this on Android.

```
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this in a Firebase Cloud Function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// or
// import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// Using Cloud Firestore
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

// Using Realtime Database
admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

Or simply:

```
Date.now()
```

Comment: I tried doing this: exports.getServerTime = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
But it's displaying this error >> Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /getServerTime from this server.

Comment: Returning Date.now() on android works fine but not on web.

Comment: Then that is a permissions issue. I suggest reading this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511677/firebase-cloud-function-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url-200-fr)