# Firebase App Distribution "Your client does not have permission to get URL"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

When I try downloading my `.apk` on Firebase console I get below error

Also my testers see the same error after they download the app to their devices

```
403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /app-binary-downloads/firebase-app-distro/
app-binaries/669991850214/1:669991850214:android:
a1b40a09ea252e2c79eb27/9ed419fe-03fe-4947-8f2c-c2a8e7e88461.apk from this server. That’s all we know
```

I did some modifications in Google Cloud and added new roles to my admin user, I understand that this is a permission issue

```
Firebase App Distribution Admin
```

Anyway that didn't help, any suggestions what should I do?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, but I can't even download the app. I, like other testers, see a screen on which the versions of the application are displayed, and it is also suggested to download the App Tester, but when trying to do this, the error "403 Your client does not have permission to get URL..." occurs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase cloud function "Your client does not have permission to get URL /200 from this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511677/firebase-cloud-function-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url-200-fr)

Answer (score 3):

**In my case**

It seems like Google restricted access to some services to certain locations. Using US VPN solved my problem.