# Trigger cloud function programatically from internet with Authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a service (web client) in AWS which needs to trigger a cloud function in GCP, I want to keep this secured so I cannot allow all users to invoke the mentioned cloud function, but I want to allow my service in AWS to invoke the mentioned cloud function.

I have searched the internet and I have seen following links: [link1](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#gcloud), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511677/firebase-cloud-function-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url-200-fr) but I am unable to find a solution.

all the mentioned solutions talk about generating the required idToken manually but since it is a service I don't have the option to generate the idToken manually, I tried to use service-accounts with keys.json file option but it throws following error:

```
request https://us-central1-multi-service-app-js.cloudfunctions.net/helloHttp with target audience https://us-central1-multi-service-app-js.cloudfunctions.net/helloHttp

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/helloHttp</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are asking for a general advice, I would suggest to have a look at a GCP Workload Identity Federation. Here are some links:

[GCP - Workload identity federation Overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation)

[GCP - Configuring workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation)

[GCP - Specific configuration description](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#mapping_service_identities)

[Medium - Keyless API authentication- Launching GCP workloads from AWS](https://medium.com/google-cloud/keyless-api-authentication-launching-gcp-workloads-from-aws-b715b4e6c99a)

[YouTube - AWS to GCP sans service account keys!! - Workload Identity Federation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgzuLEdHcO0)

[YouTube - GCP - Workload Identity Federation - Access GCS Bucket From AWS Lambda Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh0mJwFo9Ak)

One may find plenty of other Workload Identitfy Federation sources of information which are not necessarily AWS related.

Comment: And don't use a service account key file!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
I am unable to use GCP Workload Identity Federation to trigger cloud function although I am able to trigger deployment using GCP WIF, I think there may be a bug at google end at the GCP {GoogleAuth} api, I have posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909062/how-to-use-google-workload-identity-federation-to-trigger-cloud-function-http) If you get any time please have a look.