# How to use google workload identity federation to trigger cloud function (http) from AWS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to trigger cloud function (authorized) from AWS EC2 Instance ( service ) and I am trying to use Google workload identity federation for this.

I have been successful in listing cloud storage buckets using workload identity federation following this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgzuLEdHcO0) but I am unable to apply the same login for cloud function invokation.

I have followed below steps:

1. Created an AWS EC2 Instance with an IAM role.
2. Created GCP workload identity federation pool.
3. Created a service account with permission to call the mentioned cloud function.
4. Generated a clientLibraryConfig.json file by binding WIF pool with Service account.

I don't have an organization so I am unable to allow federation in organization policies ( is it possible to do it without this )

I am trying to use node js at the to trigger cloud function following is my code:

```
function main(
) {

  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const url = 'https://us-central1-multi-service-app-js.cloudfunctions.net/helloHttp',
  const targetAudience = 'https://us-central1-multi-service-app-js.cloudfunctions.net/helloHttp'

    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
    const res = await client.request({url});
    console.info(res.data);
  }

  request().catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
}

main();
```

and I am getting following error:

```
Cannot fetch ID token in this environment, use GCE or set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to a service account credentials JSON file.
```

I have already set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to clientLibraryConfig.json & GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT env variables using `export` but I still get this error.

========================================

Update:
I tried to use deployment manager api with workload identity federation to deploy 2 compute instance resources and it worked.
I was earlier also able to list buckets using WIF but the cloud function api does not work, I even tried to use python sdk for calling cloud function api using WIF but I got following error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n')
```

my best guess is since cloud function requires fetching ID Token before it can call the cloud function url, the fetching ID token part of the api is failing and since it is failing for both node sdk and python sdk I am suspecting that there is a bug in {GoogleAuth} of 'google-auth-library' which is only affecting the id token fetch part of the api.

I have opened following ticket with GCP for this issue: [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263760674)

Comment: Your config seems good. But the organization miss could be the issue.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think so too, but then the question is how is the cloud storage example working ?

Comment: did you figure out @JayantSeth?

Comment: may be you can use http api to get id token using STS token 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#external-idp

Comment: @rbkannan, I have not figured it out, using HTTP API might work, we applied a workaround to this problem by handling authentication at our end and keeping the endpoint unauthenticated.

Comment: Yeah i tried with HTTP API and it works, added the solution below

Answer (score 0):

We can use the rest api provided by google to obtain identity token

AWS CalledIdentityToken -> GCP STS token -> GCP Service account Identity token

and call the cloud function with the identity token

```js
import querystring from 'querystring';
import aws4 from 'aws4';
import axios from 'axios'

const targetResource = "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/<replace-me-gcp-project-id>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<replace-me-pool-id>/providers/<replace-me-provider-id>";
const cloudFunctionUrl = 'https://us-central1-workflow-id-pool.cloudfunctions.net/function-1';

/**
We create GetCallerIdentity Token and sign with aws4
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds#rest
*/
function createTokenAWS() {
    const params = {
        Action: 'GetCallerIdentity',
        Version: '2011-06-15'
    };
    const requestUrl = `https://sts.amazonaws.com/?${querystring.stringify(params)}`;

    const request = {
        host: 'sts.amazonaws.com',
        path: '/?' + querystring.stringify(params),
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Host: 'sts.amazonaws.com',
            'x-goog-cloud-target-resource': targetResource
        }
    };

    aws4.sign(request)

    const token = {
        url: requestUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: []
    };
    for (const key in request.headers) {
        token.headers.push({ key, value: request.headers[key] });
    }

    // The token lets workload identity federation verify the identity without revealing the AWS secret access key.
    console.log('Token:');
    console.log(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(token)));

    return token;

}

// We pass the AWS caller identity token to get the STS token
async function getStsToken(token) {
    try {
        var data = querystring.stringify({
            'audience': targetResource,
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange',
            'requested_token_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token',
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
            'subject_token_type': 'urn:ietf:params:aws:token-type:aws4_request',
            'subject_token': encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(token))
        });

        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: data
        };

        const response = await axios(config)

        return response.data;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

}

/**
* We get the Identity token using the Ststoken
* https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#external-idp
*/
async function getIdToken(stsToken) {
    let data = JSON.stringify({
        "audience": cloudFunctionUrl
    });

    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/<replace-me-service-account-email>:generateIdToken',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${stsToken.access_token}`
        },
        data: data
    };

    const result = await axios.request(config);

    return result.data;
}

// finally we call the cloud function url with id token
async function getRequest(token) {
    let config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: cloudFunctionUrl,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };

    const result = await axios.request(config);

    return result.data
}


export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const token = createTokenAWS();
        const stsToken = await getStsToken(token);
        const idToken = await getIdToken(stsToken);
        const result = await getRequest(idToken.token);

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(result),
        };
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            statusCode: 401,
            body: 'failed'
        }
    }
};
```

References from GCP docs:

1. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds#rest
2. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token#external-idp

Note: I tested this from Lambda only but i believe it should work with Ec2 as well.